# Best way to provide attic access to difficult to reach areas

Tags: attic

I would like to make it easier to access the difficult to reach parts of my attic. This is for maintenance and repairs (e.g., I would like to install some new recessed lighting and run some new wiring to different parts of the house).

My house is shaped like a U with three distinct but connected attic areas:
[image]

In two of the areas, there is direct attic access via a trapdoor ladder. However, there is no direct attic access from the master bed area and I have not yet made it over to this area as it is very difficult to reach. The attic above the kitchen / dining area has flooring in part of it for storage, but it's still difficult to get to the part where it joins the attic area above the living room.

This is the view in the attic above the living room looking towards the other two spaces:
[image]

The red circles are roughly where it joins the other two spaces.

What is  the best way to add permanent or semi-permanent easy access from the location in the picture to the other two areas? I've tried searching for this, but my google skills are not strong enough. I mostly find discussions of people wanting full on flooring or wanting an attic catwalk with a truss roof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to have a truss roof, but what you want appears to be a catwalk.

Bring up boards and screw them down where you want to go. Then go ahead and rent a blower and fill those joists with insulation. If you are unwilling to do blown-in for some reason, fill under your catwalk area with unfaced batts before screwing it down; then get around to filling the rest. The present insulation is ...pathetic.

If you can get 1" rough lumber it's cheaper, and stronger than planed material at 3/4". 3/4" ply or OSB will work, as will 3/4" planed boards, unless you are planning to **try** to break them by jumping up and down between joists. If you are, use 2x8's side by side (you can space them an inch apart for more width without risking falling through the gap between them.) 1.25" OSB would be another approach if you expect to be abusive to the catwalk. Reclaimed pallets are a potential material source if money is tight.

I suggest screwing it down because then you can easily remove it, if it's in the way, but you don't risk the situation with loose boards of having them shift so that one end is no longer supported and drops you through the ceiling when you step on it.

I'm also a fan of tossing some lights up there if access is more than once in a very great while.

Comment: We found ourselves with tons of pallet wood. Pallet wood is garbage to begin with, we couldn't do anything with it but burn it.  I would not press my weight on it unless I jointed and planed it down flat enough for glue to adhere, then did 2 crosswise layers glued.  But that's way too much work for the quality you'd get.

Comment: depends on the pallets. They vary.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was thinking, but I couldn't find good information on what types of boards / OSB / Plywood to use. Everyone immediately starts talking about flooring for storage. I will check the local hardware stores to see what makes the most sense.